# Visual Studio 2019 .NET SDK not found

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, dotnet-sdk

Problem encountered on https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/dotnet/hello-world-tutorial/install Operating System: Windows Home x64
Version: 3.1.401
Visual Studio 2019

I am getting an issue with installing the .NET SDK, at first when I went into Visual Studio 2019 it said that I was missing the .NET runtime SDK so I installed it like it asked and restarted my computer. I then went on to Visual Studio 2019 again, and the same issue arose, I went into my command prompt and typed `dotnet --list-sdks` and it displayed no SDKs. I have all of the runtimes installed, but it says "No SDKs were found". I tried re-installing the SDKs but the same problem persists. I even went as far as to re-install IIS. Whenever I make a simple console app it opens it, but when I look in the solution explorer tab it says there are 0 projects and when I go to run it, it just says "attach" where "run" used to be, and the key shortcut doesn't work anymore either to run it.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

[image: Image 4]

Comment: I think I read another post somewhere in the past 24 hours where it was claimed that a certain SDK installer was botched, and that you need to install it from the download page: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/current I can't find the post anymore though.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the Microsoft site is installing the **x64 SDK version** by default and is having a conflict with multiple versions on your computer. I'm saying this because of the `dotnet --info` result in your PrintScreen is showing just the **x86 Runtimes**.

Apparently you can't have both versions installed easily.

I recommend you to try uninstalling the x86 versions and stick with the x64. You can also check if you have both versions installed by consulting the **installed programs** on your computer.

**Rick Strahl** made a nice post about this problem in his blog: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Apr/20/Adventures-in-NET-SDK-Installation-SDKs-not-Showing-Up

Comment: Thanks, I managed to figure out how to fix it, I had to manually install the sdk by downloading the binaries, deleting the sdk folder contents, and pasting the new binaries in. That fixed it straight away, although visual studio still doesn't recognise it.

Answer (score 0):

There’s is .NET Framework and .NET Core those are two SDK‘s, you probably downloading the .NET Framework instead of the .NET Core you want.

Comment: No, I am definitely installing the .NET Core SDK